# Pandas - export dataframe column as integer preserving null values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to export my dataframe to csv with values in column POSITION formatted as integers not as float. After import from csv to df my data is correctly displayed:

```
POSITION
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
```

Then during some operations (sort_values, drop_duplicates, add empty values with np.nan) on POSITION column data gets changed to float:

```
POSITION
1.0
2.0
NULL
3.0
4.0
```

I have managed to convert df back to integer using astype(np.int64) method (pd.to_numeric did not worked) and unwanted zeros has disappear. But all this is gone during export to csv. I also have NULL values in this column so I have replaced them to some fake value which I wanted to reset back to NULL. But replacing fake value brought back unwanted float formatting.

---

This has not removed float:

```
df['POSITION'] = df['POSITION'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

This has removed floating but added dummy value "-1":

```
df['POSITION'] = df['POSITION'].fillna(-1).astype(np.int64)
```

This has removed dummy value "-1" but also every value in POSITION column:

```
df['POSITION'] = df.POSITION.replace(-1, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

If I've alternatively to "replace" used below code I got "-1" removed but float format was back again:

```
df.loc[df['POSITION'] == -1, 'POSITION'] = np.nan
```

Comment: `np.nan` is treated as float. As the result, the whole column is treated as float.

Comment: Use the new nullable integer dtype in pandas 0.24.0+: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#integer-na

Comment: Your first dataframe is already in float as well

Comment: @QuangHoang I have made this change:    df.loc[df['POSITION'] == -1, 'POSITION'] = ''     that is replace dummy values to empty string instead of "np.nan" and it worked OK. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @root  I have tried this:    df['POSITION'] = df['POSITION']..astype(np.int64)   and it returned ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: That is not the nullable integer dtype.  Read the docs I posted. You want `.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())` or `.astype('Int64')`.